# Use data from CoreData in label

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

world! I work in SwiftUI, I want to use data from CoreData in label.

Use `likedDBE.isLiked` instead of `cellViewModel.isLiked`. How can this be implemented?

```
Button(action: {
    let likedDBE = LikedDBE(context: self.managedObjectContext)
    likedDBE.name = cellViewModel.card.name
    likedDBE.price = cellViewModel.card.price
    likedDBE.isLiked = cellViewModel.isLiked
    do{
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: cellViewModel.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart") //In this place
        .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
        .foregroundColor(cellViewModel.isLiked ? .red : .black) //And in this place
    
})
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: I want to save the like, but this code does not save it, I want to do it already with the current Core Data model

Comment: Get rid of the `cellViewModel` and use an `@ObservedObject var likedDBE: LikedDBE`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869061/swiftui-how-to-fetch-core-data-values-from-detail-to-edit-views/70901886?noredirect=1#comment125404314_70901886) sample

Comment: Is there another way? I have your way in conflict with mine: `@ObservedObject var cellViewModel: ModelsViewModel = ModelsViewModel()
    
    init(cardData: Model) {
        self.cellViewModel.card = cardData
    }`

Comment: There may be another way, but you need to produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We have no idea how you have everything set up. With the Core Data model, a picture of each entity is needed as well.

Comment: Save or use in the label, now you are saying two different things. Whichever it is, you need to explain yourself much better.

Comment: @ruzaykina the conflict is with the logic you are trying to implement. You can't create an object in a `Void`/`action` and expect to access that object outside that `Void` immediately (without setting it appropriately in a variable at a shared level), especially an `ObservableObject`. CoreData objects have to be observed with `@ObservedObject` or `.sink` if you want to see changes. The `@ObservedObject`option is the much simpler solution until you understand the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use `likedDBE.isLiked` in the Button `label` part, because it is only available in the Button `action` part. So
move the `likedDBE` outside the `Button` `action`, for example:

```
// somewhere appropriate in your code and accessible to the button
var likedDBE = LikedDBE(context: self.managedObjectContext)
likedDBE.name = cellViewModel.card.name
likedDBE.price = cellViewModel.card.price
likedDBE.isLiked = cellViewModel.isLiked

// just keep the saving in the button action.
Button(action: {
    do{
        try self.managedObjectContext.save() // <--- here keep this
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: likedDBE.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")   // <--- here can use likedDBE
        .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
        .foregroundColor(likedDBE.isLiked ? .red : .black)   // <--- here can use likedDBE
})
```

Comment: What is wrong with using cellViewModel.isLiked in the button label as op was doing?

Comment: nothing wrong with using `cellViewModel.isLiked`, the OP question was `Use likedDBE.isLiked instead of cellViewModel.isLiked. How can this be implemented?`. Hey, if this is what the OP wants to do, for what ever reason, this is what he/she can do to use `likedDBE.isLiked`. Who knows what's going on here.

Comment: But now you have completely changed the logic, instead of creating a new instance each time the button is pressed you are updating the same instance

Comment: I want to keep the "like" state even after restarting the application and the only thing I came up with is to do it via CoreData, in the current version with `CellViewModel.isLiked`, the like disappears after restarting the application